# How to build visual studio project with clang-cl.exe and link libstdc++?

Tags: windows, llvm, libstdc++, libc++, clang-cl

I want to compile my vs project with `clang-cl.exe` in visual studio and use standard c++ library like `libc++` or `libstdc++`. It seems that `libc++` is not supported on Windows platform. Is there a right way to compile with `clang-cl.exe` and link standard c++ library？

Or do I have to use `msvc` and Windows c++ library?

Comment: Clang-cl simulates cl, therefore you should also use the MSVC STL + UCRT. The MSVC STL has the same license as llvm's libc++.